# AWS lambda S3 trigger taking long time to get invoked - up to 3 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've configured an AWS lambda trigger which is watching every change in a S3 bucket.

For what I understand, the lambda invocation is asynchronous, so I'm not supposed so wait a "real time" behavior.

But it's taking something about 3 minutes to invoke the lambda.

Is this normal? There's some type of configuration that can be done to reduce this waiting time?

I was wondering if pushing S3 notifications to an SNS topic and this topic invoke the lambda can be an improvement, but there's no any article that suggests this can indeed be an improvement.

Comment: how are you building your lambda? are you keeping it warm?

Comment: This shouldn't be caused by cold start.  Unless your lambda is *crazy* heavy to initialize, there's no way that's going to take 180 seconds.  " taking something about 3 minutes to invoke" this is a very long time.  While I don't have any guesses what the problem is I encourage you to consider it  something you shouldn't have to endure.

Comment: It's not so much that the "lambda trigger is watching every change". Rather, the Amazon S3 service triggers the Lambda function when an activity happens that matches the trigger configuration. So, it's a "push" rather than a "poll". The invocation of the Lambda function should be near instant. It would _not_ be faster to put SNS in the middle, since that is just adding more activity to the process flow. You might want to experiment by creating a new bucket, adding a Lambda trigger and observing the speed of the invocation. This might identify whether the issue is related to the bucket (size?).

Comment: What is your evidence that it's taking about 3 minutes to invoke the Lambda function?